# Django 2 - Could not parse the remainder: ' 'upvote.png'' from 'static 'upvote.png''

Tags: django

I am having a issue regarding static files and Django.

My main project is called "produchunt" (it is a clone of the real website) which contains "account" and "products".

I successfully add a static folder in "producthunt" for static file.

Now, I am trying to add a "upvote" image on the products app.

I did the following:

- Add the image on the static folder of the main app "producthunt"
- Write the template of "products"
- Run python3 manage.py collectstatics

BUT I am having this error: **Could not parse the remainder: ' 'upvote.png'' from 'static 'upvote.png''**

The urls.py in "producthunt" is:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('products/', include('products.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The settings.py in "producthunt" is:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'producthunt/static/'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

The url.py in "products" is:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('create', views.create, name='create'),
    path('<int:product_id>', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

The temaplte "detail.html" of "products" is:

```
<img src="{{ static 'upvote.png' }}" alt="Upvote">
```

However, I am having the error: **Could not parse the remainder: ' 'upvote.png'' from 'static 'upvote.png''**

Many thanks

Comment: It is `{% static ... %}` with `{% ... %}`, not `{{ }}`.

Comment: Thank you! It worked, many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote:

```
<img src="{{ static 'upvote.png' }}" alt="Upvote">
```

With `{{ .. }}` but this is used for *variables*. For a template *tag*, one uses `{% .. %}`, so:

```
<img src="{% static 'upvote.png' %}" alt="Upvote">
```